# How to remove values from a list of list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a list as

```
[['Name', 'Place', 'Batch'], ['11', '', 'BBI', '', '2015'], ['12', '', 'CCU', '', '', '', '', '2016'], ['13', '', '', 'BOM', '', '', '', '', '2017']]
```

I want to remove all the '' from the list.

The code I tried is :

```
>>> for line in list:
...     if line == '':
...         list.remove(line)
...
print(list)
```

The output that it shows is:

```
[['Name', 'Place', 'Batch'], ['11', '', 'BBI', '', '2015'], ['12', '', 'CCU', '', '', '', '', '2016'], ['13', '', '', 'BOM', '', '', '', '', '2017']]
```

Can someone suggest what's wrong with this ?

Comment: Where do the nested lists come from? It would be better to create them without the `''` in the first place.

Comment: @mkrieger1  I have a raw file which is not properly delimited. I converted to list and hence the output. Wanted to remove those unwanted values.

Comment: What I meant was: If you showed us *how* you created the lists, we could probably tell you how you could *avoid* the `''` entries, and you wouldn't need to remove them again.

Comment: (might be related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @mkrieger1 That would be even better. I would make a sample file and edit the post with the code i executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
a = [['Name', 'Place', 'Batch'], ['11', '', 'BBI', '', '2015'], ['12', '', 'CCU', '', '', '', '', '2016'], ['13', '', '', 'BOM', '', '', '', '', '2017']]
b = [[x for x in y if x != ''] for y in a]  # kudos @Moses
print(b)  # prints: [['Name', 'Place', 'Batch'], ['11', 'BBI', '2015'], ['12', 'CCU', '2016'], ['13', 'BOM', '2017']]
```

Your solution does not work because `line` becomes the entire sublist in every step and not the elements of the sublist.

Now it seems that you are trying to modify the original list in-place (without creating any additional variables). This is a noble cause but looping through a list that you are modifying as you are looping is not advisable and will probably lead to your code raising an error (`IndexError` or otherwise).

Lastly, do not use the name `list` since Python is using it internally and you are overwriting its intended *usage*.

Comment: An explicit test might be better, since this filters out all *falsy* values

Comment: @MosesKoledoye True. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're running your test on the sublists not on the items they contain. And you'll need a nested `for` to do what you want. However removing items from a list with `list.remove` while iterating usually leads to unpredictable results.

You can however, use a *list comprehension* to filter out the empty strings:

```
r = [[i for i in x if i != ''] for x in lst]
#                       ^^ filter condition
```